# What are all the default plugins used by maven?

Tags: java, maven

From what I read, maven cycles through the lifecycle phases and goals invoked through the command line and it simply cycles through the mentioned phases and goals. The defaults in pom.xml make sure that maven runs sensible defaults by always running a series of plugin goals according to `packaging` [using default bindings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings).

Also, if I only and only want to download dependencies and do nothing else, I can call `mvn dependency:generate-sources`.

So my question is:

1. If we run `mvn install`, it also downloads the dependencies mentioned in the pom.xml? Does this happen because calling `install` calls all the phases up till `install` including `generates-sources` which is bound to dependency plugin by default?
2. If not, who is responsible for fetching all the dependencies? Maven core or some other plugin?
3. If yes, the list of plugins invoked by default does not seem to be exhaustive. What other plugin bindings exist in pom.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. N/A
3. All maven projects have, at their base the "[Super POM](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html)" which lists all of the defaults for maven. You can look there for everything. This "Super POM" is placed as the parent for any POM that doesn't list a parent explicitly.

Comment: There's the lifecycle definitions, which are buried in XML files in plugin jar files, no easy way to visualize them.

Comment: This is what I was missing! Thanks a lot. :)